# Extracting year from a column of string movie names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data, having two columns, "name" and "gross" in table called train_df:

```
gross       name
760507625.0 Avatar (2009)
658672302.0 Titanic (1997)
652270625.0 Jurassic World (2015)
623357910.0 The Avengers (2012)
534858444.0 The Dark Knight (2008)
532177324.0 Rogue One (2016)
474544677.0 Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace (1999)
459005868.0 Avengers: Age of Ultron (2015)
448139099.0 The Dark Knight Rises (2012)
436471036.0 Shrek 2 (2004)
424668047.0 The Hunger Games: Catching Fire (2013)
423315812.0 Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Man's Chest (2006)
415004880.0 Toy Story 3 (2010)
409013994.0 Iron Man 3 (2013)
408084349.0 Captain America: Civil War (2016)
408010692.0 The Hunger Games (2012)
403706375.0 Spider-Man (2002)
402453882.0 Jurassic Park (1993)
402111870.0 Transformers: Revenge of the Fallen (2009)
400738009.0 Frozen (2013)
381011219.0 Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 2 (2011)
380843261.0 Finding Nemo (2003)
380262555.0 Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith (2005)
373585825.0 Spider-Man 2 (2004)
370782930.0 The Passion of the Christ (2004)
```

I would like to read and extract the date from "name" to create a new column that will be called "year", which I will then use to filter the data set by specific year.
The new table will look like the following:

```
year    gross   name
2009    760507625.0 Avatar (2009)
1997    658672302.0 Titanic (1997)
2015    652270625.0 Jurassic World (2015)
2012    623357910.0 The Avengers (2012)
2008    534858444.0 The Dark Knight (2008)
```

I tried the apply and lambda approach, but got no results:

```
train_df[train_df.apply(lambda row: row['name'].startswith('2014'),axis=1)]
```

Is there a way to use contains (as in C# or "isin" to filter the strings in python?

Comment: _"I tried iloc but it is not working"_: What did you try, and why did it not meet your expectations? Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]. "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic here. Helpful links to review: [tour], [ask], [on-topic](/help/on-topic)

Comment: I have updated the question with a much better idea of what the data look like and the expected return to avoid any negative comments.  thank You

Comment: You still haven't included a [mre] to show what you did and how it didn't work. Your question is still essentially "implement this feature for me"

Comment: I tried to use lo or iloc, but they are for specific indices of values and not for actual values of the string.  So that is not working.  Then, I tried the panda query() and panda .get_value(), which was also a dead-end.  I kind or stuck.  I am looking for a query that I can use to filter the string, similar to the SQL query, "Select * from table where name like'%2006%'" or something similar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know for sure that your years are going to be at the end of the string, you can do

```
df['year'] = df['name'].str[-5:-1].astype(int)
```

This takes the column `name`, uses the [`str` accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) to access the value of each row as a string, and takes the `-5:-1` slice from it. Then, it converts the result to `int`, and sets it as the `year` column. This approach will be *much* faster than iterating over the rows if you have lots of data.

---

Alternatively, you could use regex for more flexibility using the [`.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) method of the `str` accessor.

```
df['year'] = df['name'].str.extract(r'\((\d{4})\)').astype(int)
```

This extracts groups matching the expression `\((\d{4})\)` ([Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/lGZ2Ep/1)), which means capture the numbers inside a pair of parentheses containing exactly four digits, and will work anywhere in the string. To anchor it to the end of your string, use a `$` at the end of your regex like so: `\((\d{4})\)$`. The result is the same using regex and using string slicing.

---

Now we have our new dataframe:

```
          gross                                               name  year
0   760507625.0                                      Avatar (2009)  2009
1   658672302.0                                     Titanic (1997)  1997
2   652270625.0                              Jurassic World (2015)  2015
3   623357910.0                                The Avengers (2012)  2012
4   534858444.0                             The Dark Knight (2008)  2008
5   532177324.0                                   Rogue One (2016)  2016
6   474544677.0   Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace (1999)  1999
7   459005868.0                     Avengers: Age of Ultron (2015)  2015
8   448139099.0                       The Dark Knight Rises (2012)  2012
9   436471036.0                                     Shrek 2 (2004)  2004
10  424668047.0             The Hunger Games: Catching Fire (2013)  2013
11  423315812.0  Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Man's Chest (2006)  2006
12  415004880.0                                 Toy Story 3 (2010)  2010
13  409013994.0                                  Iron Man 3 (2013)  2013
14  408084349.0                  Captain America: Civil War (2016)  2016
15  408010692.0                            The Hunger Games (2012)  2012
16  403706375.0                                  Spider-Man (2002)  2002
17  402453882.0                               Jurassic Park (1993)  1993
18  402111870.0         Transformers: Revenge of the Fallen (2009)  2009
19  400738009.0                                      Frozen (2013)  2013
20  381011219.0  Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 2 (...  2011
21  380843261.0                                Finding Nemo (2003)  2003
22  380262555.0  Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith (...  2005
23  373585825.0                                Spider-Man 2 (2004)  2004
24  370782930.0                   The Passion of the Christ (2004)  2004
```

Answer (score 1):

You can a regular expression with `pandas.Series.str.extract` for this:

```
df["year"] = df["name"].str.extract(r"\((\d{4})\)$", expand=False)
df["year"] = pd.to_numeric(df["year"])

print(df.head())
         gross                    name  year
0  760507625.0           Avatar (2009)  2009
1  658672302.0          Titanic (1997)  1997
2  652270625.0   Jurassic World (2015)  2015
3  623357910.0     The Avengers (2012)  2012
4  534858444.0  The Dark Knight (2008)  2008
```

The regular expression:

- `\(`: find where there is a literal opening parentheses
- `(\d{4})` Then, find 4 digits appearing next to each other

  - The parentheses here means that we're storing our 4 digits as a capture group (in this case its the group of digits we want to extract from the larger string)
- `\)`: Then, find a closing parentheses
- `$`: All of the above MUST occur at the end of the string

When all of the above criterion are met, get those 4 digits- or if no match is acquired, return NaN for that row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
df = ['Avatar (2009)', 'Titanic (1997)', 'Jurassic World (2015)','The Avengers (2012)', 'The Dark Knight (2008)', 'Rogue One (2016)','Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace (1999)','Avengers: Age of Ultron (2015)', 'The Dark Knight Rises (2012)','Shrek 2 (2004)', 'Boiling Point (1990)', 'Terror Firmer (1999)', 'Adam's Apples (2005)', 'I Want You (1998)', 'Chalet Girl (2011)','Love, Honor and Obey (2000)', 'Perrier's Bounty (2009)','Into the White (2012)', 'The Decoy Bride (2011)','I Spit on Your Grave 2 (2013)']

for i in df:
    mov_title = i[:-7]
    year = i[-5:-1]
    print(mov_title) //do your actual extraction
    print(year) //do your actual extraction
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def getYear(val):
    startIndex = val.find('(')
    endIndex = val.find(')')
    return val[(int(startIndex) + 1):endIndex]
```

Am not much of a python dev, but i believe this will do. You will just need to loop through passing each to the above function. On each function call you will get the date extracted for you.